# Ruby on Rails Testing with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test with Ruby on Rails with a MySQL database. When attempting to run the test each test fails with the same reason:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Table 'db_test.session_cleaners' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `session_cleaners`
```

I created a session_cleaners table with a primary key and am now getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `session_cleaners` () VALUES ()
```

I doubt I need the `session_cleaners` table but I'm not sure what else to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should run the migrations and prepare the test database:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

This will take care of everything provided you have valid migrations.

You'd better read [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-three-environments) - there's plenty of information that people don't even realise.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't help.  I created a new test database and set it up properly but am still getting the "session_cleaner" error.

Answer (score 0):

There were two things that I did to fix this:

1. Update the MySQL gem so that I was using 2.7.  I'm on Ruby 1.8.6/Rails 2.3.10 so this gem was required
2. Create a session_cleaner table with one field: id. The id is not a primary key and does allow null.

These two things made it so I could prepare the test environment